# So confused on how to use Spring boot logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app which I am struggling to get logging working with a rolling appender strategy.

Here's the relevant part of my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>phoenix</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-client-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.commons.pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

When I just run my app with the pom.xml left alone, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
```

I read up on doing exclusions, so I figure I need to add the exclusion to the boot starter, like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then when I run it, I get this other error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/maven/repo/phoenix/phoenix/4.1.0-client-hadoop2/phoenix-4.1.0-client-hadoop2.jar). If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

So it's talking about some conflict I guess with the phoenix driver but I don't understand why. When I load my pom.xml and look at the Dependency Heirarchy and look for that jar, it doesn't list anything under it that I can try to exclude.

So at this point I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: That jar is likely bundling some dependencies inside it. Check inside the JAR and try to get a version without bundled dependecies. I can't even find it in maven. Where is this JAR from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove logback do this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```